# What are the differences between @Mocked, @Injectable, and @Capturing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

First, I define a class, let's say `Robot`.

```
public class Robot {

    private Vision vision;

    public Object recognizeObject(List<List<Integer>> frames) {
        vision = new Vision();
        return vision.recognize(frames);
    }
}
```

Class of `Robot` has several dependencies, one of them is `Vision`.

```
public class Vision {

    public Object recognize(List<List<Integer>> frames) {
        // do magic stuff, but return dummy stuff
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then in the test class, I simply test the invocation of `recognize()`.

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class RobotTest {

    @Test
    public void recognizeObjectWithMocked(@Mocked final Vision vision) {
        List<List<Integer>> frames = new ArrayList<>();
        vision.recognize(frames);

        new Verifications() {{
            vision.recognize((List<List<Integer>>) any);
            times = 1;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void recognizeObjectWithInjectable(@Injectable final Vision vision) {
        List<List<Integer>> frames = new ArrayList<>();
        vision.recognize(frames);

        new Verifications() {{
            vision.recognize((List<List<Integer>>) any);
            times = 1;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void recognizeObjectWithCapturing(@Capturing final Vision vision) {
        List<List<Integer>> frames = new ArrayList<>();
        vision.recognize(frames);

        new Verifications() {{
            vision.recognize((List<List<Integer>>) any);
            times = 1;
        }};
    }
}
```

Based on these tests, I think that `@Mocked`, `@Injectable`, and `@Capturing` can be used interchangeably.

- Is that correct?
- If the answer is no, then is there any case that only
  `@Mocked`/`@Injectable`/`@Capturing` is possible and cannot be replaced by
  other one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `@Injectable` mocks a single instance (e.g. a test method's parameter). Not every instance used inside the test context.
- `@Mocked` will mock all class methods and constructors on every instance created inside the test context.
- `@Capturing` is basically the same as `@Mocked`, but it extends mocking to every subtype of the annotated type (convinient!).

Another difference of `@Injectable` is that only fields marked with this annotation are considered for injection inside `@Tested` instances.

The difference should be pretty clear now.